# Get Date from DateTime control

Tags: java, swt

I know this might be a simple question but Im new to Java, my experience is mostly with PHP or C#.

Im working on an eclipse RCP project and using Google Window Builder.

All I need to do is get the date from a **DateTime** control named: `dateTimeDOB`

It must return the date in this format (dd/mm/yyyy) if the day or month value is a single digit it must have a preceding "0".

I think the DateTime control Type is

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime
```

so for example:

```
String strDate = dateTimeDOB.getDate("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd tell us the type of `dateTimeDOB`. The variable name isn't particularly important, but the type certainly is...

Comment: ok : org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime Control, Is this what you were after ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    DateTime dateTimeDOB = ...

    int day = dateTimeDOB.getDay();
    int month = dateTimeDOB.getMonth() + 1;
    int year = dateTimeDOB.getYear();

    String strDate = (day < 10) ? "0" + day + "/" : day + "/";
    strDate += (month < 10) ? "0" + month + "/" : month + "/";
    strDate += year;
```

Comment: Thanks, coming from C# I was hoping for a nice elegant 1 liner.

I couldnt find the right method in code completion and was hoping to avoid the...getYear() .....getDay()...approach. (lol)

Comment: getMonth() returns an integer between 0 and 11

Comment: @IEnumerable: There *is* a one liner - see my answer. You still need `getYear()` etc though, as I can't see anything in the `DateTime` control to give the value as a composite `Calendar` or anything similar.

Answer (score 13):

A cleaner approach (IMHO):

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateTimeDOB.getDay());
instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateTimeDOB.getMonth());
instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateTimeDOB.getYear());
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(instance.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at the [`CDateTime`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php) widget, where you have

```
Date date = cDateTime.getSelection();
```

and overall usability. The drawback is that it isn't part of SWT but an additional library.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the control already gives you the year/month/day separately, you just need to format those values, which you can do using `String.format`:

```
String text = String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d",
                            dateTimeDOB.getDay()
                            // getMonth() returns a value in the range [0, 11]
                            dateTimeDOB.getMonth() + 1,
                            dateTimeDOB.getYear());
System.out.println(text); // 03/06/2012 or whatever
```

Note that this format would be misunderstood in the US, and may be inappropriate in other cultures too. Whether that's important or not depends on your app.

Whether you go directly from single values to text or via `Calendar` (or a similar type) as per Tom Seidel's answer partly depends on how your code hangs together. If you *definitely* want to convert from the UI control to the text format, and no code in between needs to ever know about this information as a date, then what I've written is okay. However, if you need to pass the value between different methods etc then it makes sense to convert it to a more natural data type. I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), and in this case its `LocalDate` type. That way you don't need to worry about time zones, apart from anything else.